# Store - PHP Error was encountered when tried to export order details in store

Tags: expresso-store, php, expresso

Good day,

An error was encountered when I was trying to export order details to PDF in Store Module.

Following are the errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered:
Severity: Warning ;  
Message: Illegal string offset 'hex';   
Filename: include/style.cls.php ;  
Line Number: 1418;

Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent
```

Version of EE and Store are 2.6.1 and 1.64 respectively.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? It's probably best you email support@exp-resso.com with instructions on how to reproduce the issue so that we can take a look into this for you.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil My version of PHP is PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug  6 2013 12:19:53). Thank you for your advice. I will definitely send a ticket to support@exp-resso.com.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in DOMPDF, the pdf library we use. We will release Store 1.6.5 soon with an updated version of this library, but if anyone wants to test this sooner please email support@exp-resso.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the PDF generation library Store uses (dompdf). It only happened on servers running PHP 5.4 or newer.

This has been fixed in Store 1.6.5:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_165